# How to mail output of shell script as a cron job

Tags: linux, bash, email, cron, bash-scripting

I've created a cron job that runs a shell script.  I'd like the shell script to run and capture it's output and have it emailed upon completion.  Here's what I have so far, but the mail message body is empty.

I've tried all of the following:

```
/root/myscript.sh | tee output.txt | mail -s "Email subject" me@mymail.com

/root/myscript.sh | tee output.txt | mail -s "Email subject" me@mymail.com &> /dev/null

/root/myscript.sh | tee output.txt && mail -s "Email subject" me@mymail.com < output.txt &> /dev/null

/root/myscript.sh > tee output.txt && mail -s "Email subject" me@mymail.com < output.txt &> /dev/null
```

All of these run properly, but they produce an email with an empty body.  Running the script does produce output on stdout.

Comment: What is in "output.txt"? The first one should work fine. Does your script's output go to stdout or stderr?

Comment: Does your version of cron not support emailing stdout automatically?  It's a pretty standard thing...

Comment: Does `output.txt` have any contents after running your scripts? Maybe the terminal output you saw was on standard error: if so you need to redirect that as well, as in `/root/myscript.sh 2>&1 | ...`.

Comment: @AFH Please write this as an answer.  Here's what worked for me `/root/myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee output.txt | mail -s "Email subject" me@mymail.com`.

Comment: @AFH After further testing, the simpler `/root/myscript.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Email subject" me@mymail.com` also works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most likely reason for losing screen text on redirection is that the output was being sent to the standard error device. This will be confirmed if `output.txt` is empty after running the command.

To redirect standard error as well as standard output you need to add `2>&1` to your commands, as in:

```
/root/myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee output.txt | mail -s "Email subject" me@mymail.com
```

You should then see all your script's output in `output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I was also able to do this without using `tee`.